# a singular noun after the word "mass"

Tags: meaning

The narrator is talking about charred papers in the begining, but then he says

> Look at this mass of charred paper in the corner.I'll save this burnt
>   paper and look it over later.

I dont understand, was there just one leaf of paper? If yes, can just one leaf make a mass? I thought a mass consists of many things.
Please explain it to me.
Thank you

Comment: Have you checked the meanings of 'mass' in a dictionary?

Comment: Yes, i have. That didnt help me

Comment: If you haven't already, also check the definition of "paper".

Comment: There is a lot of paper, and that is plural.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Paper* here is a **mass noun** ([Grammar Handbook](http://www.cws.illinois.edu/workshop/writers/massnouns/)), which means that, rather than being a countable quantity of leaves, *paper* (and therefore the noun phrase *charred paper*) refers to the material of the mass. The material is being emphasized, rather than the form of the leaf or page.

Compare these examples, the first using another mass noun (*iron*) in a similar situation and the second using *paper* as a mass noun in another situation.

> The ancient village of Newstead, where **this mass of iron** was found many years ago, lies at the eastern extremity of the valley of Melrose ... (*[Notice of a mass of meteoric iron...](https://books.google.com/books?id=WTQAAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA5&lpg=PA5&dq=%22this%20mass%20of%20iron%22&source=bl&ots=CZLta6w3HI&sig=ACfU3U3KruvzpnfRFl861eNPSq16gYtU9w&hl=en&ppis=_e&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjii42SgfXnAhXPmOAKHV7wBTkQ6AEwBnoECCMQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22this%20mass%20of%20iron%22&f=false)*, 1862; iron denotes the material of the mass)
>
> Make original stationery by stamping **several sheets of paper** with the stamp. (*[Creative Art and Activities](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Creative_Art_and_Activities/ERoGYckR8hkC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22several%20sheets%20of%20paper%22&pg=PP47&printsec=frontcover)*, 2004; while there are multiple sheets involved, *paper* denotes the material and therefore remains singular)

Finally, it is also possible to have a *mass of papers*. That merely relies on the count definition of paper, and emphasizes the number of sheets of paper.

> To do our work, we all have to read a **mass of papers**. ("Brevity," Winston Churchill, Memo, 9 August 1940. [Quoted at University of York](https://www.york.ac.uk/about/organisation/governance/council/information/guidance/)).

Comment: For a complete answer perhaps you should also point out that "paper" is also used as a count noun. The Op's "narrator" is clearly using the word in both ways - which is perfectly legitimate.

Comment: I was just doing that. :) You're absolutely right that it helps complete the answer.

Comment: Excellent. I now feel able to upvote the answer.

Comment: @TaliesinMerlin Thank you for your full answer. So as i understood when he said "papers" he meant sheets of paper, and when he says just paper he means like a document which can have a lot of sheets but be in a form of ledger. Is it right?

Comment: @Helen Paper can be both a mass and a count noun. You can talk about "charred papers" - which means "charred sheets of paper". Or you can refer to all the papers collectively, simply as a "mass of paper".

Comment: @WS2 Thanks a lot! I got it!